# Minimum value of $|A - B |$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $B = \{ x : x/3 \in \mathbb{Z}  \ , -4 \lt x \le 12\}$ and $A = \{ x^2 - m : x \in \mathbb{Z} \ , \ -3 \lt x\le m\}$ . The value of $|A  \cap B| $ is $3$ . Find minimum value of $|A - B |$ . The only way that I can do is trying different numbers for $m$ but it isn't convincing for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $A-B = A\cap B^c$. Second,$$A = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B) \implies |A-B| =|A \cap B^c| = |A|-|A\cap B|=|A|-3.$$
So $|A-B|$ is minimized when $|A|$ attains its minimum provided that $A \cap B=3$. Obviously, $|A| \ge 3$. As such, $A = \{-m, 1-m, 4-m, \cdots, m^2-m\}$, and $|A| = m+1$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $m\ge 2$. Consequently, $$|A-B| = |A|-3=m-2.$$
Starting from $m=2$, we find the least $m$ such that $|A \cap B|=3$. You will quickly find that $m=4$ results in $|A \cap B|=3$. As such, the minimum value of $|A-B|=4-2=2.$

Comment: Why $|A| = m+1$ ?

Comment: Also why didn't you accept $m = 2$ and $ m = 3$ ?

Comment: We are looking for a set $A$ such that $|A \cap B|=3$. Note that $B = \{-3,0,3,6,9,12\}$. For $m = 2,3$, $|A \cap B|\neq 3$.

Comment: Thanks and why $|A| = m + 1$ ?

Comment: For $m \ge 2$, $A = \{\color{red}{0}^2-m, \color{red}{1}^2-m, \color{red}{2}^2-m, \cdots, \color{red}{m}^2-m\}$. Can you compute $|A|$?

Comment: Yes , Thanks a lot .

Comment: If we change the conditions of the question such that $m$ would be very large , then how we would find $m$ ?